# Spring REST api not working while hosted remotely

Tags: ajax, spring, rest, spring-security, cors

I have written a spring rest service. When i was running it on `localhost` it was running well

```
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/basicSignup",
            type:"POST",
            contentType:"application/json",
```

but when i tried & hosted on some remote server

```
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://X.X.X.X/api/v1.0/basicSignup",
            type:"POST",
            contentType:"application/json",
```

it throwing error

In chrome

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://X.X.X.X/api/v1.0/basicSignup. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8084' is therefore not allowed access.
```

In console i see that in `Method` tab it show `options`

In mozilla also it shows `OPTIONS`.

```
Response Headersview source
Allow   GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length  0
Date    Sat, 15 Aug 2015 15:15:07 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-He...    content-type
Access-Control-Request-Me...    POST
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
DNT 1
Host    X.X.X.X
Origin  null
Pragma  no-cache
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
```

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cors

Answer (score 1):

As @JB's comment says, you might need to implement [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Basically, the [single origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) wouldn't allow JavaScript from one domain, say `http://localhost:8084` to make AJAX calls to another domain, say `http://X.X.X.X` by default. There are some mechanisms for handling this, but people seem to prefer CORS, because generally it looks most convenient and powerful.

[Spring Lemon](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon) exhibits how to use CORS in details. Below is an example from another project of mine:

1. In the client code, I would set up these ajax options initially (or along with each call)

   ```
   $.ajaxSetup({    // Initialize options for AJAX calls

       crossDomain: true,

       xhrFields: {
           withCredentials: true
       }
       ...
   });
   ```
2. At the server side, have a filter which will set the CORS headers. The latest version of Spring (which would come along with Spring Boot 1.3) has an [easier way](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) to configure CORS at the server side. But, in one project using Spring Boot 1.2, I would have it like this:

   ```
   @Component
   @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
   public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {

       @Value("${applicationUrl:http://localhost:8084}")
       String applicationUrl;

       public void doFilter(ServletRequest req,
               ServletResponse res,
               FilterChain chain)
       throws IOException, ServletException {

           HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
           response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
               applicationUrl); // "*" does not work when withCredentials = true;
           response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
               "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
           response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age",
               "3600");
           response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
               "x-requested-with,origin,content-type,accept,X-XSRF-TOKEN");
           response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"); // needed when withCredentials = true;

           HttpServletRequest request =  (HttpServletRequest) req;

           if (!request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS"))
              chain.doFilter(req, res);
       }

       public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

       public void destroy() {}
   }
   ```
3. Set `applicationUrl` in `application.properties`, like this

   ```
   applicationUrl: http://X.X.X.X
   ```

Comment: How about calling server side services from a file let say `file:///home/manish/test.html` here its simply a html file stored in a directory . So here also above approach will work?

Comment: The browser won't even let you do AJAX requests from a page served from the file system.

Comment: i am running my android aap in my mobile so in that case how will handle request comming from mobile as that is not `localhost://`

Comment: Before doing a cross-origin request, the *browser* asks the server if it allows browsers to do that. And if the server says no, the *browser* prevents it. If you're not sending requests from a browser, nothing will prevent you from doing a cross origin request. BTW, it's not cross-origin, since the android application is not a web page and thus has no origin.